# ORDER BY FIELD ignoring excluded records

Tags: mysql, sql-order-by

I have to filter a set of ids which i need to keep in a specific order. The problem is, when the filter (in this case *shops.sector*) excludes some records, the ORDER BY FIELD syntax gets invalid. The error message is: “Column 'id' in order clause is ambiguous”

Here is the complete query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT `companies`.id FROM `companies` 
LEFT OUTER JOIN `shops` ON shops.company_id = companies.id 
WHERE (companies.id IN (96296,1,53585) AND shops.sector = 'Mobile') 
ORDER BY FIELD(id, 96296,1,53585) LIMIT 0, 30;
```

Is there any way to keep the order without knowing the filtered result first? I want to keep this in only one query if possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you have two or more table with a column with the same name.
you must specify what id are you ordering by, like `companies.id` or `shops.id`

Comment: this would be more specific, but that is not solving the problem. when the filter doesn't exclude any of the records given in IN() everything works fine

Comment: i am sorry, you were right. this is the simpliest answer. thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try using

```
ORDER BY FIELD(companies.id, 96296,1,53585)
```

or

```
ORDER BY 
    CASE 
        WHEN companies.id = 96296 THEN 1 
        WHEN companies.id = 1 THEN 2
        ELSE 3
    END
```